# Nhibernate/linq query is extremely slow

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I am updating a project written in c#/wpf and it makes use of nhibernate and sql server. When i tested the program i noticed it was very slow when retrieving a specific list from the database.

Below is the data access code snippet:

```
public static List<Ticket> GetListFromPeriod(DateTime beginDatum, DateTime eindDatum)
    {
        List<Ticket> list = new List<Ticket>();
        using (var session = NhibernateHelper.OpenSession())
        {
            using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                list = session.Query<Ticket>()
                    .Where(x => x.Tijdstip.Date <= eindDatum && x.Tijdstip.Date >= beginDatum).ToList();
            }
        }
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            item.IsSaved = true;
        }
        return list;
    }
```

This little piece of code is the troublemaker and takes about **90** seconds to retrieve 558 objects:

```
list = session.Query<Ticket>()
.Where(x => x.Tijdstip.Date <= eindDatum && x.Tijdstip.Date >= beginDatum).ToList();
```

Some additional information:

- **Ticket** has a 1 to many relationship with **TicketRecord**
- **Klant** (= A Customer in English) has a 1 to many relationship with **Ticket**
- **PapierSoort** (= paper category in English) has a 1 to many relationship with **TicketRecord**

Mappings:

```
public TicketMap()
    {
        Table("tblTicket");
        Id(x => x.Id)
            .Column("TicketId")
            .UnsavedValue(0)
            .Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Tijdstip)
            .Column("Tickettijdstip")
            .Not.Nullable();
        References(x => x.Klant)
            .Column("KlantId")
            .Not.Nullable();
        HasMany(x => x.TicketRecordsAsList)
            .Table("tblTicketRecord")
            .Inverse()
            .KeyColumn("ticketid").Cascade.All();            
    }


public TicketRecordMap()
   {
       Table("tblTicketrecord");
       Id(x => x.Id)
           .Column("ticketrecordid")
           .Not.Nullable();
       Map(x => x.Prijs)
           .Column("ticketrecordprijs")
           .Not.Nullable();
       Map(x => x.Gewicht)
           .Column("ticketrecordgewicht");
       References(x => x.Soort)
           .Column("soortid")
           .Not.Nullable();
   }

public KlantMap()
    {
        Table("tblKlant");
        Id(x => x.Id)
            .Column("klantid")
            .Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Naam)
            .Column("klantnaam");
        Map(x => x.RijksregisterNr)
            .Column("klantrijksregisternr");
        Map(x => x.Idnr)
            .Column("klantidnr");
        Map(x => x.Adres)
            .Column("klantadres");
        Map(x => x.Actief)
            .Column("actief")
            .Not.Nullable();
    }

public PapierSoortMap()
    {
        Table("tblSoort");
        Id(x => x.Id)
            .Column("papiersoortid")
            .Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Naam)
            .Column("papiersoortnaam")
            .Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Prijs)
            .Column("papiersoortprijs");
        Map(x => x.IsDefault)
            .Column("papierisdefault")
            .Not.Nullable();
    }
```

Nhibernate helper:

```
public static class NhibernateHelper
{
    private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

    private static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
    {
        get
        {
            if (_sessionFactory == null)
                InitializeSessionFactory();

            return _sessionFactory;
        }
    }

    private static void InitializeSessionFactory()
    {
        _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
            .ConnectionString(x => x.FromConnectionStringWithKey("DBconnect"))
                          //.ConnectionString(
                          //    @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Solutions\KassaOPM\KassaOPM.UI\DB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
                          .ShowSql())

            .Mappings(m =>
                      m.FluentMappings
                          .AddFromAssemblyOf<KlantMap>()
                          .Conventions.Add(FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Helpers.DefaultLazy.Never()))
            .BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    public static ISession OpenSession()
    {
        return SessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }

}
```

In the SQL Server Profiler i found 3 different query's that are being excecuted:

The first one (only occurs in the beginning):

```
exec sp_executesql N'
select ticket0_.TicketId as TicketId3_, ticket0_.Tickettijdstip as Ticketti2_3_, ticket0_.KlantId as KlantId3_ 
from tblTicket ticket0_ 
where dateadd(dd, 0, datediff(dd, 0, ticket0_.Tickettijdstip))<=@p0 and dateadd(dd, 0, datediff(dd, 0, ticket0_.Tickettijdstip))>=@p1',N'@p0 datetime,@p1 datetime',@p0='2015-04-22 00:00:00',@p1='2015-03-22 00:00:00'
```

second and third one:

```
exec sp_executesql N'
SELECT klant0_.klantid as klantid0_0_, klant0_.klantnaam as klantnaam0_0_, klant0_.klantrijksregisternr as klantrij3_0_0_, klant0_.klantidnr as klantidnr0_0_, klant0_.klantadres as klantadres0_0_, klant0_.actief as actief0_0_ 
FROM tblKlant klant0_ 
WHERE klant0_.klantid=@p0',N'@p0 int',@p0=4235

exec sp_executesql N'
SELECT ticketreco0_.ticketid as ticketid2_, ticketreco0_.ticketrecordid as ticketre1_2_, ticketreco0_.ticketrecordid as ticketre1_4_1_, ticketreco0_.ticketrecordprijs as ticketre2_4_1_, ticketreco0_.ticketrecordgewicht as ticketre3_4_1_, ticketreco0_.soortid as soortid4_1_, papiersoor1_.papiersoortid as papierso1_1_0_, papiersoor1_.papiersoortnaam as papierso2_1_0_, papiersoor1_.papiersoortprijs as papierso3_1_0_, papiersoor1_.papierisdefault as papieris4_1_0_ 
FROM tblTicketrecord ticketreco0_ inner join tblSoort papiersoor1_ on ticketreco0_.soortid=papiersoor1_.papiersoortid 
WHERE ticketreco0_.ticketid=@p0',N'@p0 int',@p0=27342
```

I suspect that there is something wrong with the code, but i can't seem to figure out what the problem is.

If you need any other information please ask and i will do my very best to give you what you need.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the one-to many mappings related to the tickets meeting the date condition seems to be fetched in your business object, according to the second and third queries.

Maybe you should declare your one to many relations as lazy to avoid the extra (and maybe unnecessary) loading.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response, i did what you suggested and mapped the one to many relations as Lazy but unfortunately it did not have any effect.

Comment: Did you remove the  Default lazy convention from your configuration in the InitializeSessionFactory function ?  Not sure if related.

Comment: Well, since i think you are right that the default lazy convention is the problem i am trying to fix this. In order for Nhibernate to work every method and property in my classes from the business layer needs to be **virtual**. Since this project makes use of Caliburn.Micro (MVVM) the propertychanged methods are in the dll of Caliburn.Micro so i can't make them virtual. If i can fix that problem i will post my solution here for other people to see. But in the meantime i will mark your answer as the solution since you pointed me in the right direction, thanks for your help!